# How to get previous month end date exclude Saturday and Sunday in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following query.
How to get previous month end date exclude `Saturday` and `Sunday` using `linux`

for example if current date is `2023-01-07` then previous month end date should be `2022-12-30` (`Friday`) not `2022-12-31` as the date falls on  `Saturday`.

Using following code I am able to get last month end date.

```
export CurrentMonthStartDate=$(date -d ""$(date '+%F') "" '%Y-%m-01')+
export PreviousMonthStartDate =$(date -d "$CurrentMonthStartDate -1 month" "+%F")
export PreviousMonthendDate=$(date -d "$PreviousMonthStartDate +1 month -1 day" "+%F")
```

expected output

| current_date | expected output |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-04 | 2023-01-31 |
| 2023-03-06 | 2023-03-28 |
| 2023-04-03 | 2023-03-31 |
| 2023-05-08 | 2023-04-28 |

- current_date : any day (`YYYY-MM-DD`)
- expected output: Previous Monthend date (`YYYY-MM-DD`)
- expected output date shouldn't fall on `saturday` and `sunday`

Comment: I have added screenshot of expected output

Comment: I have saved the expected output as text.

Comment: What do you mean by "in shell"?  `date` is not a shell builtin, so clearly you allow the use of external tools.  Which tools are you allowing?  For date manipulations, I tend to use `perl`.

Comment: BTW, you probably shouldn't be using `export` here -- that copies variables into environment space, which is a limited resource (the resource is per-process, but still: the more/larger environment variables you have, the shorter your maximum command-line length gets, until eventually you can't run other programs at all). When you don't _need_ an environment variable, better to stick to a regular shell variable; just `var=value`, not `export var=value`.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C
for ymd in 2023-02-04 2023-03-06 2023-04-03 2023-05-08; do
    weekday=$(date -d "${ymd%-[0-9]*}-01 -1 day" "+%a")
    case "$weekday" in
        Sun)
            delta=-3
        ;;
        Sat)
            delta=-2
        ;;
        *)
            delta=-1
        ;;
    esac
    date -d "${ymd%-[0-9]*}-01 $delta day" "+%F"
done
```

##### Output

```
2023-01-31
2023-02-28
2023-03-31
2023-04-28
```

Comment: if d=2023-01-28 then expected output should be previous month end date(excluding saturday and sunday)
2022-12-30

Comment: Check updated answer...  ^^

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` using an array:

```
d=( $(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +'%F %u') )
if (( ${d[1]} < 6 )); then echo ${d[0]}; else date -d "${d[0]} - $(( ${d[1]} - 5 )) days" +%F; fi
```

#### edit

It produces the expected output, you are probably calling it wrong because your question states *current date*. So here it's for any date

```
#! /bin/bash

fdom() {
    local -r d="$1"
    echo "${d/%-[0-9][0-9]/-01}"
}

lwdopm() {
    local -r d="$1"
    local -r a=( $(date -d "$(fdom "$d") -1 day" +'%F %u') )
    if (( ${a[1]} < 6 )); then echo ${a[0]}; else date -d "${a[0]} - $(( ${a[1]} - 5 )) days" +%F; fi
}

for ymd in 2023-02-04 2023-03-06 2023-04-03 2023-05-08; do
    lwdopm "$ymd"
done
```

and the output

```
2023-01-31
2023-02-28
2023-03-31
2023-04-28
```

Comment: if date is 2023-05-05 then expected output should be 2023-04-28.
The condition is not getting satisfied in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

##### Using a Perl's one-liner:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -E '
    for (@ARGV) {
        s/-\d{2}$//;
        my $ymd = Time::Piece->strptime("${_}-01", "%Y-%m-%d");
        my ($dow, $month, $dom, $hour, $year) = split / /, $ymd - ONE_DAY;
        my $gap;
        if ($dow eq "Sun")    { $gap = 3*ONE_DAY }
        elsif ($dow eq "Sat") { $gap = 2*ONE_DAY }
        else                  { $gap = ONE_DAY   }
        ($dow, $month, $dom, $hour, $year) = split / /, $ymd - $gap;
        my $dateold = Time::Piece->strptime(
            "$dow $month $dom $year", "%a %b %d %Y");
        say $dateold->strftime("%F");
    }
' 2023-02-04 2023-03-06 2023-04-03 2023-05-08
```

##### Output

```
2023-01-31
2023-02-28
2023-03-31
2023-04-28
```

Answer (score 0):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c), credits for **@hotnuma**:

```
// https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22660860#p22660860
// gcc finddate.c -o finddate
// ./finddate 2023-02-04 2023-03-06 2023-04-03 2023-05-08
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STRSIZE 10

bool finddate(const char *part)
{
    if (!part || strlen(part) != STRSIZE)
        return false;

    char inbuff[STRSIZE+1];

    strcpy(inbuff, part);
    inbuff[STRSIZE-2] = '0';
    inbuff[STRSIZE-1] = '1';

    struct tm tm;
    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));

    strptime(inbuff, "%Y-%m-%d", &tm);

    tm.tm_mday -= 1;
    mktime(&tm);

    // Saturday
    if (tm.tm_wday == 6)
    {
        tm.tm_mday -= 1;
        mktime(&tm);
    }

    // Sunday
    else if (tm.tm_wday == 0)
    {
        tm.tm_mday -= 2;
        mktime(&tm);
    }

    char outbuff[STRSIZE+1];

    strftime(outbuff, STRSIZE+1, "%Y-%m-%d", &tm);
    printf("%s\t%s\n", part, outbuff);

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int n = 1;

    printf("orig\t\tresult\n");

    while (n < argc)
    {
        finddate(argv[n]);

        ++n;
    }

    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```